# How to get value from Asp.Net Mvc Form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Before I submitting the updating form , I want to check if Status value is not less than ziro (below ziro) 
I mean this part of the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I get this specific value if I use this javascript to send the hole form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


         $("#btnUpdateProduct").click(function () {

             // Some where here or after var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize(); I must check if
             // Value of @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status .....

             var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

             $.ajax({

                 type: "POST",
                 url: "/Home/EditProduct",
                 data: myformdata,
                 success: function () {

                     $("#updateModal").modal("hide");
                     location.reload();

                 }

             })
         })

     })
```

And this is my hole View Form ..

```
@model Products.Models.Product

<div>
    <form id="myForm">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Product</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountryId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModelId)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" id="btnUpdateProduct"/> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: what if you try `$("#Status").val()` to get the input field value ?

Comment: @Shyju Thank you for response , I tried that Before but it gives me empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your editor an id the following could work for validating your Status.

Razor Change.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "MyStatus" } })
```

Then here is your javascript you could try.

```
var status = document.getElementById("MyStatus").value;
if(status >= 0)
{
     $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "/Home/EditProduct",
                 data: myformdata,
                 success: function () {

                     $("#updateModal").modal("hide");
                     location.reload();

                 }

             })
}
else
    alert("Status is not greater than zero");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd block the user from even hitting submit until your criteria is met. Guess just personal preference.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 checkMe" })

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnUpdateProduct').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.checkMe').change(function(){
       if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 0) {
         $('#btnUpdateProduct').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
         $('#btnUpdateProduct').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
     });

     $("#btnUpdateProduct").click(function () {

         // Some where here or after var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize(); I must check if
         // Value of @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status .....

         var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

         $.ajax({

             type: "POST",
             url: "/Home/EditProduct",
             data: myformdata,
             success: function () {

                 $("#updateModal").modal("hide");
                 location.reload();

             }

         })
     })
 })
```